# Cannot install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects Extension

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installer, visual-studio-2015, development

I would like to create installers for some of my software packages, so I am attempting to use the Visual Studio Add-On known as *Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects Extension*. However, I am not having much luck. Upon running the installer I get the following message:

> Microsoft Visual Studio is required, but it is not installed on this computer. Please install it and retry.

I do not understand why I would get this message, when I indeed have *Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Express for Windows Desktop* installed on my computer. Here is the window when the issue happens:

[image]

Comment: You need to switch to the Community edition of Visual Studio

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, and do you know why?

Comment: VS Express Edition do not support extensions. As mentioned above install the Community Edition.

Comment: Just a quick question, is it legal to deploy apps with community edition?

Comment: @StevieV - As for the reason, because what your trying to install, requires it.  Why question the answer you get?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install *Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects*

[image: Arrow pointing to Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects]

But you should install *vs_community*  file inside  `VS2015 Community Edition\vs2015.com_enu`

[image: Arrow pointing to Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 vs_community]

Comment: What is the path?